# Decrypting a polyalphabetic cipher

Tags: decryption

I'm currently trying to crack a ciphertext with three rotating substitution ciphers. I've tried dividing the cipher up into three parts and do text frequency analysis since I know the language but no luck when trying to peace together the parts. It keeps coming back as gibbirish.

Are there any tips or tool that you would suggest?

Comment: Can you just bruteforce it?

Comment: Brute Force and text frequency analysis are good for monoalphabetic substitution. In general they may not be useful for polyalphabetic ciphers. I don't know your cipher, but maybe the Kasiski-test is a good starting point. Another idea is finding the key length.